# Creating modal dialog with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When someone clicks my label, i want to open a small "Alert" like element, and i want to be able to use the modal's buttons functionality.

Is there a jquery library / extension that can easily do something like this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#MyLabel', function() { 

     openModal();

});
```

Comment: `alert("Show your message")`

Comment: And even jquery dialog

Comment: i dont know this event name what is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a fundamentally simple task in jQuery UI. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisStanyon/eDMmy/)

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen  : false,
    modal     : true,
    title     : "A Dialog Box",
    buttons   : {
              'OK' : function() {
                  var textValue = $('#myTextBox').val();
                  alert('The value of the text box is ' + textValue);
                  //Now you have the value of the textbox, you can do something with it, maybe an AJAX call to your server!
              },
              'Close' : function() {
                  alert('The Close button was clicked');
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
                }
});
```

Comment: how can i get witch button clicked ?

Comment: Check this out: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/453/)

Answer (score 2):

An easy and quick way might be using some UI framework like **[Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)**, which has out-of-the-box HTML components. After you include the framework in your app, you can copy & paste templates and display modals and whatnot.

**In your js script:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#MyLabel', function () {
    
    // show the modal
    $('#MyModal').show();

    // validate the modal is fully loaded to DOM
    $('#MyModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

        // do stuff like button click callback:
        $('.approve').on('click', function(){
            alert('approved');
        })
    })
});
```

**For the template you can use this example taken from [Boostrap's documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) :**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">Modal body</div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <!-- Approve Button -->
                <button class="approve btn btn-primary" type="button">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its button inside model. It will not work on `onClick` function

Comment: Hi @ZainFarooq, see my update above. It covers the buttons functionality

Comment: I also edited this code... If your works fine. You can continue with yours

Comment: @DotBot Thanks man, this help me a lot!! grate answer!